# What is ".el" in relationship to JavaScript/HTML/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I couldn't find much from Googling, but I'm probably Googling the wrong terms.

I'm trying to understand what the "el" in "$.el" is from here:
http://joestelmach.github.com/laconic/

```
$.el.table(
  $.el.tr(
    $.el.th('first name'),
    $.el.th('last name')),
  $.el.tr(
    $.el.td('Joe'),
    $.el.td('Stelmach'))
).appendTo(document.body);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`el` is just an identifier and it refers to an element, a DOM element, which is a convention in that library.

Comment: I was wondering if it's just a convention.  So usually people use 'el' to represent any DOM element that they are processing?  Is that the convention?

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain the explanation seeing the [source](https://github.com/joestelmach/laconic/blob/master/laconic.js) of the project in the github:

```
// If we're in a CommonJS environment, we export our laconic methods
  if(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = laconic;
  } 

  // otherwise, we attach them to the top level $.el namespace
  else {
    var dollar = context.$ || {};
    dollar.el = laconic;
    context.$ = dollar;
  }
```

The code means that $.el namespace will have the function `laconic()` and this function create elements using `document.createElement` and append to the body.

Comment: Does that mean $.el is just something they defined and is specific to this library?  It's not really a special command or function?

Answer (score 3):

`el` is a function that's been placed on the `$` object, and can be invoked to generate DOM elements:

```
$.el('table')
```

`el` also acts as a placeholder for other objects, like the `table` function:

```
$.el.table()
```

Answer (score 2):

It creates a tree of elements and appends them to body