# What is el / element? How do I use it? And why?

Tags: jquery

Pardon me if this is a n00b-ish question but if the shoe fits I'll just have to wear it. What I'm trying to say is, please type slow so I can pick up what you're laying down.

I have read this:

[What is ".el" in relationship to JavaScript/HTML/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507100/what-is-el-in-relationship-to-javascript-html-jquery)

But it didn't help me (and where I am currently on the learning curve).

I've also tried Googling but that doesnt' seem to turn up much. Perhaps I'm not using the right keywords?

Comment: It's just a variable, it has no meaning beyond the plugin mentioned in that question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is ".el" in relationship to JavaScript/HTML/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507100/what-is-el-in-relationship-to-javascript-html-jquery)

Comment: @JasonOrendorff - Seriously! The OP references that question in the question above ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is just a plugin added to jquery to help you make the DOM easily.
then

```
$.el.table(
 $.el.tr(
   $.el.th('first name'),
   $.el.th('last name')),
 $.el.tr(
   $.el.td('Joe'),
   $.el.td('Stelmach'))
).appendTo(document.body);
```

is equivalent to

```
$('body').append("<table><tr>
      <th>first name</th><th>last name</th>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>Stelmach</td>
    </tr></table>");
```

Notice that the [Laconic Plugin](http://joestelmach.github.com/laconic/) is not a native plugin of jquery.

Comment: This helps. Thanks for the contrasting examples. If they're more or less the same, then why choose one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

It is the name that the Laconic plugin uses when added to jQuery.

It's used to create elements. For example, `$.el.div('text')` does the same as `$('<div/>').text('text')`.

Comment: Thx. But if it's the same, then why? Or at least, when would I use one over the other?

Comment: It's a great plugin, but if you're using jQuery it's pretty much a useless plugin (unless you're creating a lot of nested elements in javascript, which is not really a good thing), as jQuery has all of that built in.

Comment: @ChiefAlchemist: Different people like to code in different ways, so some invent plugins to do the same thing in a slightly different way. If you could image how much work some people will lay down just to save them a little bit of work... ;)